# Short story with a female lead. She is a courier with a pouch inside her thigh

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

She has a pouch inside her thigh

- moves between locations in a tube the size of a person
- very dangerous and prestigious occupation
- a travel mistake gets you splatted between destinations
- Maybe *published* in a *best* science fiction book
- Written between 1980 and 2000

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Do you remember anything else, like what she carried in the pouch, or who she worked for?

Answer (score 11):

It sounds a little like **Friday**, by Robert Heinlein.  Here's a summary, from Wikipedia.

> "Friday is a 1982 science fiction novel by Robert A. Heinlein. It is
> the story of a female "artificial person", the eponymous Friday,
> genetically engineered to be stronger, faster, smarter, and generally
> better than normal humans. Artificial humans are widely resented, and
> much of the story deals with Friday's struggle both against prejudice
> and to conceal her enhanced attributes from other humans. The story is
> set in a Balkanized 21st century, in which the nations of the North
> American continent have been split up into a number of smaller states.
>
> Friday is a genetically engineered human (known as an Artificial
> Person or AP) in many ways mentally and physically superior to
> ordinary humans. There is great prejudice against APs so Friday
> conceals her status.  Employed as a highly self-sufficient “combat
> courier in a quasi-military organization”, traveling across the globe
> and to some of the near-Earth space colonies. Friday is returning from
> her latest mission when she is captured, tortured, raped and
> interrogated by an enemy group. She is rescued by her own people, who
> tell her that her highly critical mission was successful as her
> captors failed to find the data she was carrying in her body."

It's a novel though, not a short story. It's been a while since I read it, but a lot of your description matches what I remember - she smuggles things by concealing them in her body (don't remember if it was a pouch specifically), she works in a very dangerous occupation, and she travels around the world of the near future.

Comment: Except that her pouch was in her navel, not her thigh.  And it was a novel.

Comment: @DavidW Her navel was a novel?

Comment: But she doesn't move using a "tube the size of a person", she is certainly not in a prestigious job and travel mistakes don't get you splattered. The "courier with message in their body" made me think of *Friday* as well, but it really doesn't match the OP's description.

Comment: @RandalThor Well, after all it *was* a novel navel.

Comment: @Randal'Thor: Yes you could really get into it.

Comment: Sounds like Heinlein was influenced by William Gibson, don't it?

Comment: Yes love the novel Friday. But that is not the short story ti am try8ng to remember. The pouch to carry a small packet of data or object is in her thigh